# Age not rendering in html: VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I am new to VueJs. As a start, I am trying to create a page which on button click increases or decreases age. However, the age is not rendering on to the html. Given below are the reqd files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Events</h1>
    <button @click="add">Add a year</button>
    <button @click="subtract">Subtract a year</button>
    <p>{{ age }}</p>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      age:22
    },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
      this.age++;
    }
    subtract: function(){
      this.age--;
    }
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is missing comma symbol after add function :D .

Correct version of app.js as below :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      age:22
    },
  methods: {
    add: function(){
      this.age++;
    },
    subtract: function(){
      this.age--;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Great. Nice example